# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable di python 2.7

Tags: python, string

```
while True:
op_list = []

for op in client.longPoll():
  op_list.append(op)

for op in op_list:
  sender   = op[0]
  receiver = op[1]
  message  = op[2]

  msg = message.text
  if msg("help"):
    receiver.sendMessage('why?')

if msg("help"):
```

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable ,anyone can help me?

Comment: this cant be the correct format. `While True: ` what? Nothing?

Comment: msg("help") is almost certainly your problem - message.text is a string, and you're trying to call it with the argument "help". If you want to check if it's equal, do msg == "help"

Comment: This code is not indented correctly, please fix it so we can focus on your main problem. What do you expect `msg("help")` to do?

Comment: probably everything is contained in the `while True:`

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies on line 12. msg is a text, obvious that it cannot be a callable. You should quite certainly do an equal to if you want to compare two strings.

```
if msg == "help":
    receiver.sendMessage('why?')
```

Comment: while True:
   op_list = []

   for op in client.longPoll():
      op_list.append(op)

   for op in op_list:
      sender   = op[0]
      receiver = op[1]
      message  = op[2]

      msg = message.text
     if msg == "help":
     receiver.sendMessage('why?')   
       if msg == "help":
                    ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Can you put this code in the main question ? Can't really understand the indentation here.